# How to get a new IP address?

Tags: linux

I am running Tor on Debian via SSH (I do not have GUI).

I am making applications run inside Tor using the `torify` prefix.

Is there a quick way to get a new IP address?

Comment: Sending SIGHUP should get you a new identity. If you have `arm` installed press `x` twice for a new identity.

Answer (score 1):

You can issue the `NEWNYM` command via the control port. The [STEM documentation](https://stem.torproject.org/faq.html#how-do-i-request-a-new-identity-from-tor) has a good example:

```
from stem import Signal
from stem.control import Controller

with Controller.from_port(port = 9051) as controller:
  controller.authenticate()
  controller.signal(Signal.NEWNYM)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could just restart the service in Linux as well...

`service tor reload`

Answer (score 0):

```
printf "AUTHENTICATE \"your_password\"\r\nSIGNAL NEWNYM\r\n" | nc 127.0.0.1 9051
```